# Solr full-text search without an index?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, solr

Does solr search index content independently, or use the full-text index in the mysql table, because I have got a 22K record table that I want to enable full-text search on it, but I currently I don't have a full-text index on the table, and I can't apply it because it takes too much time, and cpu usage that the server can't handle.

if not is there any alternative that I can use to search full-text search without having the index full-text in my table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr is absolutely unaware of your backend storage and therefor it doesn't care if your tables have a full-text index (or which DBMS if any you are using)

Comment: Thanks alot, I didn't know that its completely independent